# git-daemon says 'not in whitelist' even if git-daemon-export-ok exists

Tags: git

I was trying to set up a git server.  I set up the SSH server successfully, and now I was trying to set up an anonymous git service, but it's not working properly.

I copied the sample systemd service file from the git book https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-Git-Daemon, changing only the paths to where I have the files:

```
$ cat /etc/systemd/system/git-daemon.service 
[Unit]
Description=Start Git Daemon

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/git daemon --reuseaddr --base-path=/srv /srv/src/

Restart=always
RestartSec=500ms

StandardOutput=syslog
StandardError=syslog
SyslogIdentifier=git-daemon

User=git
Group=git

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Then created a git user and group:

```
$ sudo useradd -U --system git
$ sudo usermod -d /nonexistent git
$ sudo usermod -s /usr/sbin/nologin git
$ sudo usermod -c git git
$ getent passwd git      
git:x:998:998:git:/nonexistent:/usr/sbin/nologin
$ groups git
git : git
```

Then enabled and started the service (which I'll show below that is active and running):

```
$ sudo systemctl enable git-daemon.service
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/git-daemon.service ��� /etc/systemd/system/git-daemon.service.
$ sudo systemctl start git-daemon.service
```

Then created the file to export the repo:

```
$ touch /srv/src/alx/libalx.git/git-daemon-export-ok
$ ls -l /srv/src/alx/libalx.git/git-daemon-export-ok 
-rw-r--r-- 1 alx alx 0 Jan  7 18:49 /srv/src/alx/libalx.git/git-daemon-export-ok
```

And then attempted to clone from it:

```
$ git clone git://localhost/src/alx/libalx.git
Cloning into 'libalx'...
fatal: remote error: access denied or repository not exported: /src/alx/libalx.git
```

The service complains that it's not whitelisted (but it is, isn't it?):

```
$ sudo systemctl status git-daemon.service 
��� git-daemon.service - Start Git Daemon
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/git-daemon.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Fri 2022-01-07 18:43:52 CET; 24min ago
   Main PID: 43138 (git)
      Tasks: 2 (limit: 3366)
     Memory: 528.0K
        CPU: 26ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/git-daemon.service
             ������43138 /usr/bin/git daemon --reuseaddr --base-path=/srv /srv/src/
             ������43139 /usr/lib/git-core/git-daemon --reuseaddr --base-path=/srv /srv/src/

Jan 07 18:43:52 rpi systemd[1]: Started Start Git Daemon.
Jan 07 18:43:59 rpi git-daemon[43144]: [43144] '/srv/src/alx/libalx.git': not in whitelist
Jan 07 18:50:02 rpi git-daemon[43175]: [43175] '/srv/src/alx/libalx.git': not in whitelist
Jan 07 18:50:03 rpi git-daemon[43176]: [43176] '/srv/src/alx/libalx.git': not in whitelist
Jan 07 18:52:54 rpi git-daemon[43186]: [43186] '/srv/src/alx/libalx.git': not in whitelist
```

Why am I not able to clone via `git://`?

---

If I pass a completely invalid path to clone I get the same exact output at client side, but at server side the log is different:

```
$ git clone git://localhost/src/ald/sdf/sdf.git
Cloning into 'sdf'...
fatal: remote error: access denied or repository not exported: /src/ald/sdf/sdf.git
```

```
$ sudo systemctl status git-daemon.service 
...
Jan 07 19:13:37 rpi git-daemon[43261]: [43261] '/srv/src/ald/sdf/sdf.git' does not appear to be a git repository
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just encountered this myself a few minutes ago and came across your question in the process of figuring it out.

Remove the trailing slash from the directory path at the end of your git daemon command in your systemd file. This seems to cause an issue with the whitelist as seen in the error shown in /var/log/syslog.

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/git daemon --reuseaddr --base-path=/srv /srv/src
```

After I made a similar change I was able to use the git protocol as expected.

Comment: As a side-note it *works* if base-path and repository path is the same as per example; as does stripping it. But … seems safer to always strip it.

Comment: Hmm, I first wrote `--base-path=/srv/ /srv/src/` to mimic the example as much as possible, but that also failed and produced a double slash in the log, which is why I removed one of them.  I should have removed both back then.  The example in the book would be better without trailing slashes then.